# Getting the error "CustomRoleARN:xxxxxx is not assumable for this token" while re-assigning a Role to a federated user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sts

I am trying to do the following:
i) Validate a user thru Cognito Federated Identity (mapped to CognitoPool). A Role R1 is assigned as part of this process.
ii) A want to assign a new Role R2 to this token. 
While assigning the Role R2, I am getting following error :
"CustomRoleARN: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/R2 is not assumable for this token"

I have to go this way , because I might have to create R2 runtime based on certain conditions.

R2 Trust Relationship :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/R1"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Policy Attached To R1 (not Trust Relationship):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1/*"
            ]
        },
        {
          "Effect":"Allow",
          "Action":"sts:AssumeRole",
          "Resource":"*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please let me know what I am missing.

Thanks in advance for looking.

Answer (score 0):

I got brain dead. One should call sts.GetFederationToken() in such scenario. My requirement was to assign a different Policy to already verified federated user.

I was trying to call cognito.getCredentialsForIdentity() on already verified user. I was mixing up 2 solutions. That's why I was getting the error

Thanks